# How to call multiple api concurrently and read headers using Retrofit, Coroutines with Async/Await method in Kotlin Android

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

My aim to call five apis and to get headers from those api response.
I have added my code below

Api service class

```
@GET("users")
suspend fun getUserList(): Call<List<FriendListModel>>
```

Repo class

```
suspend fun getList(): Response<List<FriendListModel>> {
    return apiService.getUserList().execute()
}
```

ViewModel class

```
 fun getFriends() {
       viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
           val data =
               async {
                   try {
                      val data = friendListRepo.getList()
                       val header = data.headers().get("id")
                       /*
                       * need to add header logic
                       */
                       Resource.success(data)
                   } catch (throwable: Throwable) {
                       when (throwable) {
                           is HttpException -> {
                               Resource.error(false, throwable.response()?.message()?:"")
                           }
                           else -> {
                               Resource.error(false,  "")
                           }
                       }
                   }

               }
           
           val res = data.await()
           mutableFriendsList.postValue(res)
       }

    }
```

My question is, am I doing it in right way because I am getting a warning in repo class saying that "Inappropriate blocking method call" since I am calling execute() method though I am calling it in suspend function.

[I referred] [Kotlin coroutines await for 2 or more different concurrent requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62965788/kotlin-coroutines-await-for-2-or-more-different-concurrent-requests).

Is there any other approach to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You should not combine `suspend` with `Call`. `Call` is for asynchronous work. `suspend` does asynchronous work synchronously by suspending. It can't be both at once. `execute` does a *blocking* synchronous fetch of the data, which shouldn't be done in a coroutine.

So, your functions should look like:

```
@GET("users")
suspend fun getUserList(): List<FriendListModel>

suspend fun getList(): List<FriendListModel> {
    return apiService.getUserList()
}
```

Then when you use it in a coroutine, you don't need `async` because you're just calling a synchronous suspend function. You also don't need to fool with Dispatchers.IO since you're only using a suspend function (not doing blocking work). I also simplified your `catch` block in this example, but that's not related to the solution (I just couldn't help myself).

```
fun getFriends() {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        mutableFriendsList.value = try {
            val data = friendListRepo.getList()
            val header = data.headers().get("id")
            /*
             * need to add header logic
             */
            Resource.success(data)
        } catch (throwable: Throwable) {
            Resource.error(false, (throwable as? HttpException)?.response()?.message.orEmpty())
        }
    }
}
```

Side note, even when you are calling blocking code, you should never need to use `async` immediately followed by an `await()` call on it. That is just a convoluted alternative to `withContext`.

Comment: `data.headers()` throws me error since I am returning a list in ApiService class that is why I returned Call interface. And also I need to call five apis concurrently (as I don't want to call one after the other).